# Convert a series of 2D XY-line plots into a 2D heatmap plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I'm pretty new to python coding, so apologies if this question has been asked before.

I have a piece of code, written by another person, which I cannot show here, but it produces a series of line plots (like this [image: X-Y line plots]).

What I would like to do is basically collapse these plots into one heatmap plot, wherein the colour shows the density of the lines in that location.

Could anyone point me in the right direction for producing these plots?

Comment: Are you capturing the functions of each plot, or the coordinates they draw through?

Answer (score 0):

[image]It looks like you are trying to draw a [2d histogram](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist2d.html#matplotlib-pyplot-hist2d), would you like help with that?

```
N=200
t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, N)
r = 5
x = r*np.cos(t)
y = r*np.sin(t)
x+=np.random.random(N)
y+=np.random.random(N)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(8,4))
ax1.plot(x,y, 'c-')
ax2.hist2d(x,y)
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use a [2D kernel density estimate plot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html) (provided by seaborn)

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(8,4))
ax1.plot(x,y, 'c-')
sns.kdeplot(x, y, ax=ax2, shade=True, cmap='viridis')
```

[image]